# Como fazer com que uma scrollbar siga o ultimo comentário em uma listBox no C#?

Tags: c#

Estou criando um Chat no C#,que irá servir como uma interação entre um Usuário e um Analista,sendo como meio para uma Ordem de Serviço,até o momento estou conseguindo e já consegui fazer com que haja a conexão de forma correta para entrar no Chat.

O meu problema é de que conforme se vai digitando no listbox a scrollbar não segue o ultimo comentário e fica para cima,e não desce seguindo os comentários.

Eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que a scrollbar siga os comentários,sem ter que fazer o usuário usar toda hora o scrollbar.

**OBS : Eu creio que não seja necessário postar alguma parte dos códigos,pois não irá ajudar muito sendo que não terá muita relevância na questão do meu problema.**

Comment: Seu sistema é Windows ou Web?

Comment: Meu sistema é Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seleccione o último item da lista:

```
listbox.SelectedIndex = listbox.Items.Count - 1;
```

Comment: Depois de adicionar a mensagem á lista...

Comment: Funcionou,muito obrigado amigo,+1 e também dei como resposta que me ajudou :)